# Functions generalized from Euler's complex formula $ e^{ iy}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are general intersection curves of $ z= \Re ( x^{iy}),$ for $ x=const? $

Are they governed by one differential equation?

Only well known is the intersection for $x= e, \,z= \cos y. $

[$\,z= \Re(x^{iy})$ Intersection](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152113/fundamental-complex-surface-plotting-including-two-real-from-euler-relation-po/152160#152160)

Comment: What is an intersection curve?  For $x$ real and positive, you have $x^{iy}=e^{i (y\log x)}$

Comment: Corrected typo, thanks.

Comment: Assuming appropriate branches,
$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}=-[\ln(x)]^2z$$
Which follows from Henry's comment.

Comment: For $x \ne e $ also , even solutions of it are all cosine curves.. is that correct?

Comment: Just one among them is a cosine curve.